# Error when reading from input line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Uses python3

```
import sys

input = sys.stdin.read() 
tokens = input.split()
a = int(tokens[0]) 
b = int(tokens[1]) 

print(a + b)
```

---

I am trying to compile this simple code in Python. HOwever it gives me Index Error:List Index out of range. I just need to compile this code and then feed 2 digits to it at input line.

Comment: Show how you run it. There's no error here and Python doesn't compile in the sense you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys

inputed = sys.stdin.read() 
tokens = str(inputed)
a = int(tokens[0]) 
b = int(tokens[1]) 

print(a + b)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.split()` splits on space. if your numbers have no space between it won't work, as they both will be in a single element (`tokens[0]`)

Demonstration:

```
>>> '12'.split()
['12']
>>> '1 2'.split()
['1', '2']
```